# Is there a way to capture the name of a browsed to file name in a form?

Tags: html, forms

I want to be able to have an option in my form where I click browse, this opens up Finder on mac or explorer on windows and I select the file.  This file name then becomes the value of my form field.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So you want just the name without actually uploading the file when the form is submitted?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications#Getting_information_about_selected_files

Comment: @JamesMontagne yes that's right

Comment: And your question is only tagged with `html`, I assume javascript is acceptable as well?

Comment: yes, I just put html because inputs are html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [`<input type="file"/>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#file-upload-state-type-file)?

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/eDJtK (Demo uses jQuery for simplicity).

Comment: aha I didn't know about that element.  I just need to be able to get the value of that text instead of the file on submit

Comment: What use is that over a plain `<input type="text"/>` or a `<textarea>`?

Comment: saves them having to type it in

Comment: would I need to store the value as a hidden form field then because I need to pass the value to the script on submit?

Comment: ok, I am having trouble getting the value of that form field of type ="file"

Comment: I can't read your mind. What exactly is the problem? Have you looked at the code in the demo?

Comment: sorry, I know, just ignore me, I'm halfway round to sorting the issue now

Comment: I figure I do have to store it as a hidden form field, that is the bit I am having trouble with, assigning the .val() of input type="file" to my hidden field is having no effect, and alerting the type="file" is showing a value so thats where Im stuck on atm

Comment: IGNORE ME!  I am clearly too tired to be coding as I have being using the wrong variable name.  Sorry.

Comment: Take a break `:)` anyway, I was going to offer this: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/Gepnx/

Comment: think I may have to.  Thank you that helps.